# How to check given date is equal to current month using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

in database the created date is like "2018-12-01 18:51:41".Based on this date i want to compare this date with current month.If current month is not equal to  created date just show alert "not in this month".

I tried this  code so  far

```
const dateTime = "2018-09-01 18:51:41";
const parts    = dateTime.split(/[- :]/);

var month = parts[1];
var day   = parts[2]; 
var year  = parts[0];

var currentdate = new Date();
var cur_month   = currentdate.getMonth() + 1;
var cur_day     = currentdate.getDate();
var cur_year    = currentdate.getFullYear();

if(cur_month==month && day >= cur_day)
{
    alert("in this month");
}
else
{
    alert("not in this month");
}
```

Can anyone help me plz?

Comment: `day` should be `parts[0]` and `year` should be `parts[2]`?

Comment: I tried the same script for todays date it seems working in chrome https://plnkr.co/edit/M9TLNOe4zeLxbvp3dJm2?p=preview

Comment: Your code working fine.

Comment: i have updated my code plz check it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to check with month and year value. Don't consider date in your condition. Have a look to my code -

```js
const dateTime = "2018-11-01 18:51:41";
const parts = dateTime.split(/[- :]/);

var month = parts[1];
var year = parts[0];

var currentdate = new Date();
var cur_month = currentdate.getMonth() + 1;
var cur_year = currentdate.getFullYear();

if (cur_month == month && year == cur_year) {
  alert("in this month");
} else {
  alert("not in this month");
}
```

Comment: How to do this condition within each function.$(".checkvat").each(function() {});If not in this month make  this checkbox will be $(this).attr("readonly", true);

Comment: If your datetime month equals to current month you want to apply readonly or you want to apply disabled `attr` on checkbox. What you actually try to achieve? @becool

Answer (score 2):

You only need to check that currentMonth === dateMonth && currentYear === dateYear. If they are then you are in the current month and don't need to check the day.